# Activate PDF/X-3 support in Scribus

Tags: graphics, printing

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with Scribus 1.4.0.rc3 and created a photo book that I would like to get printed now. From what I understand I should be using PDF/X-3 as compatibility level for the pdf export.

However even after following the instruction on the scribus[1](http://docs.scribus.net/index.php?lang=en&page=pdfx3) site to activate color management I can't seem to be activating the option. It never shows up in the compatibility drop down for the pdf export.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.. so I figured it out myself. It is important to turn on color management for the current document. This is done in File - Document Setup - Color Management. Changing it in File - Preferences - Color Management like described everywhere I found only affects new documents and not already existing ones.